# Powershell: WMI query taking too much time

Tags: powershell, wmi

Below is my WMI query to get the antivirus details from remote machines.

```
$AV = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_product where name like 'Mcafee%virus%' or name like 'F-secure%' or name like 'Symantec%'" -ComputerName $machine
```

This query is taking about 2-3 minutes to give me the output for a single machine.
I just want to know is there anyway it can be fast.
Some other alternatives.

Thanks you.

Comment: Do you really need all values from the Win32_product? It is much faster to just ask the property you want. So try not to use '*'

Comment: In general I'd shy away from using the Win32_Product class. https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/wmi/why-win32_product-is-bad-news/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use another WMI query such as the one below:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct"
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but F-secure entry not coming in this namespace.

Comment: Can you try with Namespace "root\SecurityCenter" (without the 2) and see what you get?

Comment: No output while running query.